# Show loading gif using CollagePlus grid with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using [CollagePlus](http://collageplus.edlea.com/) to create an image grid, which usage is very simple:

**HTML**

```
<div class="coll">
    <img src="css/images/gal/1.jpg" width="640" height="320"><!--
    --><img src="css/images/gal/2.jpg" width="932" height="146"><!--
    --><img src="css/images/gal/3.jpg" width="640" height="480"><!--
    --><img src="css/images/gal/4.jpg" width="1020" height="510"><!--
    --><img src="css/images/gal/5.jpg" width="640" height="320"><!--
    --><img src="css/images/gal/6.jpg" width="260" height="390"><!--
    --><img src="css/images/gal/7.jpg" width="680" height="380"><!--
    --><img src="css/images/gal/8.jpg" width="620" height="310"><!--
    --><img src="css/images/gal/9.jpg" width="940" height="520">
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.coll').collagePlus();
```

**CSS**

```
.coll{
    padding: 5px;
}

.coll img{
    vertical-align: bottom;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

And the images will appear as they load. Problem is, if the user has a very slow connection (and a lot of people have a bad connection in my zone), they won't show at all until they load, so, how can I show a loading gif on the images?

I tried to use background images, or ::after and ::before pseudo classes but since the images have `opacity: 0` until they load, they gif will be hidden anyways.

Comment: CollagePlus might create some wrapper elements for each image. Try to figure these out (use your browser's inspector) and add the background-image / :after / :before to these elements instead.

Comment: Actually it doesn't, that's the problem, it doesn't create any wrapper, it just hides the image until it has loaded and applies styles to it, then when it loads, it set's the opacity of the pic to 1, but now that you told me, I could create a wrapper with jquery each function and apply the styles for the gif to it, thanks!